# Domain Hijacking / Unrestricted EPP

Tags: security, epp

I have done a vulnerability scan on my domain, and Domain Hijacking / Unrestricted EPP who's up as a MEDIUM threat.

I can't find any information on how to restrict EPP. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: You have provided very little information in your question. From what I understand it's you registrar which should apply any restrictions on your domains. What kind of vulnerability scan have you exactly done?

Answer (score -2):

Turns out this is done at your domain host. Simply restricting changes to the domain solved it.